# How to avoid the copy when I return

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have a function which returns a vector or set:

```
set<int> foo() {
    set<int> bar;
    // create and massage bar
    return bar;
}

set<int> afoo = foo();
```

In this case, I create a temporary memory space in function foo(), and then
assign it to `afoo` by copying. I really want to avoid this copy, any easy way I
can do this in C++11? I think this has to do with the rvalue thing.

OK, update to the question: If I am going to return an object defined by myself,
not the vector or set thing, does that mean I should define a move constructor?
like this:

```
class value_to_return {
  value_to_return (value_to_return && other) {
    // how to write it here? I think std::move is supposed to be used?
  }
}
```

THanks!!!

Comment: What you've got now will not make any copies in C++11.  It may make moves, but even those will almost certainly be optimized away by [N/RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: "how to avoid the copy when I return" - compile with a compiler released not more than 10 years ago.

Comment: I'm very tempted to downvote all answers which don't mention moves/rvalues.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Where I work, "C++" means "C++03", and that is unlikely to change before 2020 at the earliest. I suspect the same is true for 90+% of professional C++ programmers. (Large organizations employ most of them, and large organizations move very very slowly.) In fact it is quite possible C++11 will turn out to be the "C99 of C++"

Comment: @Nemo: I think you're exaggerating the number of organizations that don't have C++11.  Even if you weren't, official C++ deserves to be _mentioned_, even if the answer also provides details for C++03.

Comment: Do C++11 move-constructors actually provide any benefit in this case?  It seems like they are made redundant by the the return-value optimization.

Comment: @Nemo: Nice assumption. Pity your assumptions are essentially irrelevant.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't think that he is exaggerating it. And, even if he were, `I'm very tempted to downvote all answers which don't mention moves/rvalues` is an utterly ridiculous thing to say.

Comment: @Lightness: The question specifically talks about C++11. I checked the edit history and there's no evidence it ever did not specifically ask about C++. So yes, any answer not mentioning rvalue references is deficient.

Comment: @DeadMG: Ah, on _this_ question... yes.

Comment: @DeadMG: The question was originally tagged "c++" but not "c++11". I admit I missed it in the question's text; mea culpa. Even so, RVO is a perfectly valid answer, if incomplete. Does that really deserve a downvote?

Answer (score 18):

Modem C++ compiler will implement: given a type `T`:

- If T has an accessible copy or move constructor, the compiler may
  choose to elide the copy. This is the so-called (named) [return value
  optimization (RVO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), which was specified even before C++11 and is
  supported by most compilers.
- Otherwise, if T has a [move constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors), T is moved(**Since C++11**).
- Otherwise, if T has a copy constructor, T is copied.
- Otherwise, a compile-time error is emitted.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK return value optimization works only when you construct the object directly in the return statement like this: `return (set<int>)(...);` An intelligent compiler might transform the code in the question into this form, but for more complex functions I would imagine that it won't work.

Comment: @cmaster, in OP's case, RVO will also apply. Read the wiki link in my answer regarding RVO. :)

Comment: @cmaster: Optimizing out a copy in case of returning a named variable is usually called NRVO, named return value optimization, and has been implemented years ago by most compilers.

Comment: @JohannesD: Glad to hear about it, but there's still circumstances under which it's not possible, no? I. e., you still have to think about it to ensure that the copy is really optimized away?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). A modern compiler will optimize this situation, and in straightforward situations like these, no copy will be made on any of the major compilers.

In principle, you could also create your object outside the function, and then call the function and pass the object to it by reference. That would be the old way of avoiding a copy, but it is unnecessary and undesirable now.

Answer (score -2):

I usually work around this by having function signature as

```
void foo(set<int> *x)
```

Just pass it by reference or the other option is already mentioned in the comment.

Edit: I have changed the argument type to illustrate that x could be changed.

```
      set<int> s;
      foo(&s);
```

This is only preferred when you have an old compiler. I suppose that could be the case with some of the projects.

And, better thing to do will be Either to use move semantics with c++11. Or go ahead returning the container and look into RVO in modern compilers.

Comment: I'm voting this up because it is the *only* answer that proposes passing in an output parameter. A perfect answer would include RVO and move constructors as well.

Comment: Almost tempted to vote it _down_ for proposing output parameters.

Comment: @EdS.: Output parameters are terrible.

Comment: @DeadMG  why are output parametrs such a terrible thing?

Comment: @DeadMG: That's just silly.  Of course I would just `return whatever` in most cases, but 1. it wasn't always guaranteed to avoid a copy in most situations, and 2. creating a class used in one or two places just to return more than one value is *far* more terrible.

Comment: Output parameters are not evil. Using references for them is. If I write `foo(bar)` I certainly don't want or expect bar to change, if I have to write `foo(&bar)`, I expect that the function will likely modify bar. I'm really tempted to downvote for suggesting such dangerously obfuscated code.

Comment: Using output parameters in many cases is LESS efficient on modern compilers than returning a result from a function. It may also make your code LESS readable as in many cases it will force you to use temporary variable while the returned value can be easily passed to other functions or used in expressions directly.

Comment: Functions that take output parameters are non-composable, and they're also less flexible. If tomorrow, you want an unordered_set, I have to change all my calling code. If I have `auto set = foo();` I change nothing. Output parameters are just obscure. If you want to return more than one value use a tuple, that's what it's for. It's also going to be *exactly what the compiler implements returning by value as*. Especially since the whole shebang is unnecessary because move semantics.