# Return rvalue reference from move is not persisted

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code:

```
string&& getString() {
    string s {"test"};
    return move(s);
}
```

and I tried to output:

```
cout << getString() << endl;
```

It gives me empty output.

When I use:

```
string getString() {
    string s {"test"};
    return move(s);
}
```

It works.

My question:

1. Why the first one is not working? I moved the reference so the local object should not be destroyed?
2. Does the second one do "copy" (not considering RVO)?

Comment: You never want to return `T&&`.  To return a rvalue you just return `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the first one is not working? I moved the reference so the local object should not be destroyed?

```
string&& getString() {
    string s {"test"};  // s is a local variable
    return move(s);     // move doesn't really move object, it turns the object to rvalue
}
```

You are returning an rvalue reference to a local `non-static` object.
An rvalue reference is a reference, and returning it while referring to a local object means that you return a reference to an object that doesn’t exist any more. Whether std::move() is used doesn’t matter, because `std::move` doesn't really move object, it turns the object to rvalue

> Does the second one do "copy" (not considering RVO)?

Compiler should consider RVO first then `move`(Since C++11), otherwise it should copy. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157090/how-to-avoid-the-copy-when-i-return/18157181#18157181) as well.

You just need to write:

```
string getString() {
  string s {"test"};
  return s;
}
```

Comment: So I assume I just use the second case without even using `move` and it should try to move?

Comment: sorry can you please look at this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor in the bottom, b2 "stole" b1 and b1 becomes empty. If it is just casting, how does this happen?

Comment: @texasbruce: All `std::move` does is a cast. It's the *calling* of the move constructor that actually does the moving. The cast is simply what makes calling the move constructor *possible* (unless it's a temporary or an lvalue used in certain circumstances, such as a return statement like the above). But until you actually construct a value (ie: converting the rvalue reference into an object), no movement has taken place.